# View of ViewController over ViewController: I want a drop shadow on the left?

Tags: ios, view, uikit, core-animation, dropshadow

I use this code to add a drop shadow to a view that is above another view.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(90, 0, 230, 460);

FeedsViewController *feedsViewController = [[FeedsViewController alloc] init];
[feedsViewController.view setFrame:rect];
self.feedsViewController = feedsViewController;
[feedsViewController release];

[[feedsViewController.view layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[[feedsViewController.view layer] setShadowColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
[[feedsViewController.view layer] setShadowRadius:3.0];
[[feedsViewController.view layer] setShadowOpacity:0.8];
[self.view.superview addSubview:feedsViewController.view];
```

But it does not work, why?

Comment: Some information about _how_ it doesn't work would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply forgot

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Sorry for that.